# Table Layout dip in Android

Tags: android, tablelayout

In my app i created an activity i have place a 5 continuous edit boxes inside a `table layout`, in the same activity i have `3 image buttons` and an `image view`. The UI looks good in an `320x480` device but when i tried it in a `480x854` device its not fine. I am able to arrange the `image buttons` and `image views` by giving width, height, `x` and `y axis` respectively in the coding but when i tried to do the same with table layout my app gets crashed.

How to re-size the table layout to be fit. Following is my xml file of the table layout:

```
<TableLayout
android:id="@+id/widget01"
android:layout_width="280px"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_x="34px"
android:layout_y="60px"
>
<TableRow
android:id="@+id/widget11"
android:layout_width="280px"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
>
<EditText
android:id="@+id/widget111"
android:layout_width="242px"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="18sp"
>
</EditText>
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>

<TableLayout
android:id="@+id/widget02"
android:layout_width="280px"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_x="34px"
android:layout_y="98px"
>
<TableRow
android:id="@+id/widget12"
android:layout_width="280px"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
>
<EditText
android:id="@+id/widget222"
android:layout_width="242px"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="18sp"
>
</EditText>
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid complications with `different Screensizes`, use `dip` instead of `px`

Answer (score 1):

You have to use dip unit instead of px. Don't specify the exact width and height try to give either wrap-content or fill-parent.